# provided dependencies show up in deployment assembly section

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have two modules A and B. Module A is general and can be included in many different projects. I have a custom dependency configured in the following way:

**build.gradle (module A)**

```
configurations { providedCompile }

eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += configurations.providedCompile

sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile }
    test { compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile }
}
```

The module A has a custom "providedCompile" dependency on some library (e.g. com.test.gradle.C). Like this:

**build.gradle (module A)**

```
providedCompile "com.test.gradle.C:common-tests:${myTestsVersion}"
```

Now, in module B, I have defined a dependency on module A.

**build.gradle (module B)**

```
compile project(':moduleA')
```

In module B, which is a web project, I want to use a different version of library com.test.gradle.C, e.g.

```
compile "com.test.gradle.C:common-tests:${myTestsVersion}"
```

The problem is, that in eclipse in section deployment assembly I can see the library from module A. This is because .classpath file contains

```
<classpathentry ...>
    <attributes>
        <attribute .../>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

To get rid of the attribute element I wrote the following in gradle:

**build.gradle (module A)**

```
eclipse {

    classpath.file {
        // Classpath entry for Eclipse which changes the order of classpathentries; otherwise no sources for 3rd party jars are shown
        withXml { xml ->
            def node = xml.asNode()
            def provided = node.findAll { it.@path.contains('com.test.gradle.C') }

            provided.each{ dep ->
                dep.children().clear()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I got round the problem, but I think there must be a better way for that. Can anybody help?

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way. We'll be able to take this further once Gradle can natively express `provided` (and not just for `war` projects).